# How to clone an existing Cloudflare Worker

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, wrangler

I cannot find a quick way to clone a Worker already deployed (such those created from the online dashboard). Is there a command similar to `git clone`, to obtain a local copy?

There are no references in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Now there is a way:
`npm create cloudflare@2 <original-worker-name> -- --type pre-existing`
this copies the original code, and creates everything you need to develop locally.
I didn't find it because it was inside the `npm create` command, which I wasn't looking for.